# Finding the general solution to $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+13y=0$ if $y(0)=3$ and $y'(0)=7$ using the Laplace Transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find the general solution to:
>   $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+13y=0$$ if $y(0)=3$ and $y'(0)=7$.

So I have tried solve it using Laplace transformation but cannot exceed from that....help me please

Here is what I have done so far:

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)+y'(0)+6sY(s)+6y(0)+13Y(s)=0$$
$$s^2Y(s)+7+6sY( s)+6(3)+13Y(s)=0$$
$$(s^2 +6s+13)Y(s)=25$$
$$Y(s)=\frac{25}{s^2 +6s+13}$$

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have made some sign mistakes:
$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)\color{red}{-}y'(0)+6sY(s)\color{red}{-}6y(0)+13Y(s)=0$$
Hence, given your initial conditions, you should obtain:
$$s^2 Y(s)-3s-7+6sY(s)-18+13Y(s)=0$$
$$Y(s)=\frac{25+3s}{s^2+6s+13}$$
Hence, the problem boils down to evaluating the RHS:
$$y(x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{25+3s}{s^2+6s+13}\right\}$$

---

To evaluate the Inverse Laplace Transform of $Y(s)$ in a convenient manner, we complete the square on the denominator and then write $s=(s+3)-3$ for the numerator. We then split the fraction in two, giving:
$$Y(s)=\frac{25+3s}{(s+3)^2+4}=\color{red}{\frac{16}{(s+3)^2+4}}+\color{green}{\frac{3(s+3)}{(s+3)^2+4}} \tag{1}$$

---

You can now evaluate the Inverse Laplace Transform of $Y(s)$ by applying the following well-known results: (Results **19** and **20** from the [Table of Laplace Transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf))
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{ax}\sin(bx)\right\}=\frac{b}{(s-a)^2+b^2} \tag{2.1}$$
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{ax}\cos(bx)\right\}=\frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2} \tag{2.2}$$
If you want a derivation of $(2.1)$, I derived it on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338005/partial-fractions-with-imaginary-roots-evaluating-mathcall-1-left-frac/2338203#2338203). The derivation of $(2.2)$ is very similar.

Comment: Won't you replace the -6y(0)=-6(3) to place in the initial condition of y(0)=3

Comment: @Jean You wrote $y(0)=0$. https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2373556/1

Comment: Allright, I've edited my answer since you edited your question. Though for next time, please read your question carefully before posting it.